# How to pass raw pointer of unique_ptr to a function that takes in unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

class Res {
        std::string s;
    public:
        Res(std::string arg) : s{ std::move(arg) } {
            std::cout << "Res::Res(" << s << ");\n";
        }
        ~Res() {
            std::cout << "Res::~Res();\n";
       }
    private:
       friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Res const& r) {
           return os << "Res { s = " << r.s << "; }";
       }

};

// ptr is used just to read the content of the ptr.
// No writing is done. fun2 calls another api 
// lets say api_fun that requires unique_ptr
void fun2(std::unique_ptr<Res>& uniq_ptr){
    // api_fun(uniq_ptr);
    std::cout << uniq_ptr.get() << '\n';
}

void fun1(Res* ptr){
    //std::unique_ptr<Res> tt(ptr);
    //fun2(std::move(tt));// this deletes the mem twice.
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Res> up(new Res("Hello, world!"));
    fun1(up.get());
    // up will be used here too
}
```

I am working on a project that has a `unique_ptr` variable lets say `up`. This unique_ptr
`up` is passed to a function `fun1` as raw pointer. Now inside `fun1` I have to call function `fun2` but it takes unique_ptr.

As mentioned in the comment of `fun2`. This function only reads the content of the pointer no modification is done.

How do I pass unique_ptr to `fun2` from a raw pointer?

Ps: Is there a solution without modifying the api definition?

Edit: fun2 can takes std::unique_ptr&

Comment: Why does `fun2()` take `std::unique_ptr` if it only needs to access the raw pointer?

Comment: `fun2()` uses `std::unique_ptr` let me modify it code :p

Comment: Does `fun2()` need to use the `std::unique_ptr` itself? Can't it just take the raw pointer as a parameter like `fun1()`?

Comment: `fun2()` takes the `unique_ptr` by value. That's no good, as it doesn't return it or otherwise pass it around; at the end of the function, whatever you've passed is destructed. Don't do this. Accept reference (of object, not `unique_ptr`) on the interface. You don't take ownership there, you don't need to.

Comment: @Galik nope because fun2() calls another api library that requires the unique_ptr.

Comment: It sounds like the API may not be designed correctly. A function should never accept a smart pointer unless it needs to accept ownership of the pointed to object.

Comment: @pokche Then take const reference to the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: If you have an API that needs you to give it ownership of some object then the caller of that API needs to own the object.  Your `fun1` does not own anything, so it cannot call `fun2` unless it makes a copy that it can then pass off ownership of.

Comment: I modified the fun2 to take ref of `unique_ptr`

Comment: @MilesBudnek even though fun2 takes reference of `unique_ptr`?

Comment: That still feels dodgy to me. If your function only ever needs a `Ref` object then it should just accept either a `Ref&` (preferred) or a `Ref*`. Smart pointers are not intended to be passed around the system unless transferr/sharing of ownership is required (should be rare).

Comment: @Galik what if in case of `unique_ptr` with custom deleter? Sorry I should have mentioned that but I thought it would have complicated things :p

Comment: It doesn't matter. The question is what part of the system needs to delete the object? Does it need to be deleted by one of the functions you call? Or does it need to be deleted by `main()` (in your example)?

Comment: @Galik deleted by main

Comment: Then, if none of the functions you call need to delete the object, they probably should not be receiving a `std::unique_ptr` to it. Or even a reference to a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: This is a very good programming guide: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-smart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of passing the address with get() you must release the ownership with release()

```
void api_fun(std::unique_ptr<Res> const&);

void fun2(std::unique_ptr<Res>& uniq_ptr){
  api_fun(uniq_ptr);
  std::cout << uniq_ptr.get() << '\n';
}

void fun1(Res* ptr){
  std::unique_ptr<Res> tt(ptr);
  fun2(tt);
  tt.release();
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Res> up(new Res("Hello, world!"));
    auto p = up.release();
    fun1(p);
    up.reset(p);
    std::cout << "All good" << std::endl;
}
```

but these fun1 and fun2 are not fun at all for anyone who is going to work with it later ;)

Surprisingly it looks exception-safe.

Comment: touche comrade! not fun. Why did you say it looks exception safe? Can you clarify?

Comment: My main concern with releasing any resource is if it is automatically cleared when any exception hits. Here it looks like the only moment the raw pointer is left alone is when it's passed/returned to/from the fun1(). So no matter when the exception hit's it's going to be released.

Comment: But you know. Someone adds a few lines after tt.release(), and it's no longer safe.

Comment: how would one handle that scenario? If something breaks after tt.release() inside `fun1` wouldn't the whole code break? but may be not graciously? since up.reset(p) is not called and resource is not released right?

Comment: But since the process is dead at this point, wouldn't the resource be released anyways.

Comment: I mean like the code above it looks safe - no extra work needed as long as unique_ptr construction is the first line of fun1(), and tt.release() is the last line of fun1(), and the "up" release and reset are called right before and after calling fun1().
Still, if it's some serious application just double-check if it it's exception-safe.

Comment: > But since the process is dead at this point, wouldn't the resource be released anyways.

@pokche If it's memory in app run under OS - yes. In other cases it may be not.